# How to make the submit button enabled in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here's the code:

***list.component.html***

```
    <nz-radio-group formControlName="radiostatus" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" (ngModelChange)="onChangeStatus($event)">
                  <label nz-radio nzValue="passed">Passed</label>
                  <label nz-radio nzValue="failed">Failed</label>
    </nz-radio-group>

    <div *ngIf="radioValue ==='failed'>
       <textarea nz-input placeholder="Remarks" class="remarks-textarea" type="text" name="otherRemark"
              formControlName="otherRemark" [(ngModel)]="otherRemark"
              [nzAutosize]="{ minRows: 3, maxRows: 3 }"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="mr-1" nz-button nzType="primary" type="button" [disabled]="disableSubmitBtn()"
      [nzLoading]="formLoading" (click)="saveFormData()">
      <span translate>Submit</span>
    </button>
```

***list.component.ts***

```
  disableSubmitBtn() {
       if (!this.otherRemark) {
          return true;
       }
  }
```

how to `enable` the submit button when selecting the `passed` in angular.

What I want, after selecting the `passed` on the `radio button` it should `enable` the `submit button` if it select the `failed` the `button` is `disabled` where it should fill up the remarks first which is the `textarea`  where the function `disableSubmit()`

```
if (!this.otherRemark) {
    return true;
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this:

```
 <button [disabled]="radioValue === 'passed' ?  !(radioValue === 'passed') : !(radioValue === 'failed' && otherRemark)" class="mr-1" nz-button nzType="primary" type="button" 
    [nzLoading]="formLoading" (click)="saveFormData()">
      <span translate>Submit</span>
 </button>
```

Comment: we can simplify it by the `[disabled]="radioValue !== 'passed'"` it will reduce the code.

Comment: @jithil, Please read the question again! There two case actually. 1. Button should be enable when the radio button value is 'passed' 2. The button should be enable if the radio button value is 'failed' and remark is entered

Comment: It's again more easy to append another strings.
`[disabled]="(radioValue !== 'passed') || (radioValue !=='failed' && !otherRemark)"`

Comment: @jithil, this won't work. Please check! (radioValue !== 'passed') => this returns true in case of failed radio value as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `[(ngModel)]="radioValue"` So option value with update `ngModel`

Try this:

```
disableSubmitBtn() {
  if (this.otherRemark.length == 0 || this.radioValue != "passed" ) {
    return true;
  } else if(this.radioValue = "passed" ) {
    return false;      
  }
}
```

Comment: the value of ```this.radioValue``` is ```radioValue: any```?

Comment: It's up to you.If you want use `strimg`

Comment: How'bout the ```textarea``` when it fill up it should enable the submit button

Comment: Use `this.otherRemark.length == 0` for disabling the button (Edited my answer)

Comment: it didn't enable the submit button

Answer (score 1):

```
disableSubmitBtn() {
  if (this.radioValue === 'passed') {
    return false;
  } else if (!this.otherRemark) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

It may help you

Answer (score 1):

Most simplest way i follow will be something like this:
 `[disabled]="(radioValue !== 'passed') || (radioValue !=='failed' && !otherRemark)"`

This will add the enable the button while the radio value is not `passed`. So, if the user selects any other values apart from the `passed`, it get disabled.

complete html example:

```
<button [disabled]="(radioValue !== 'passed') || (radioValue !=='failed' && !otherRemark)" class="mr-1" nz-button nzType="primary" type="button" [nzLoading]="formLoading" (click)="saveFormData()">
      <span translate>Submit</span>
 </button>
```